# Different SSL ssl_verify_clent for different SSL ports in NGINX not working

Tags: ssl, nginx

I have a definition in Nginx where by different ports, I need different SSL client verify options.

When I connect to :443/location1, Nginx will request a client cert, but will fail with "HTTP 400, Bad Request, Require Client Cert".  It seems as if NGinx uses the server rule for port 444 which has a "ssl_verify_client off" on connect, but on the route, NGinx checks to see if a client cert was given since it's rule for port 443, says client verify is required and then fails in the actual HTTP request.

I dug around and can't seem to find any docs around this.  Clearly same IP:PORT is an issue, but everything thus far indicates by PORT I can change the config but that doesn't seem to be the case.

```
server {
    listen 443;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/ssl-certs/a.cert;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl-certs/a.key;
    ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers         HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    ssl_client_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl-certs/ca.pem;
    ssl_verify_client   on;
    location /location1 {
        [..]
    }
}
server {
    listen 444;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/ssl-certs/a.cert;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl-certs/a.key;
    ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers         HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    ssl_verify_client   off;
    location /location2 {
        [..]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually figured it out.

Client rejection is mandatory, but can happen either after the connection has been made or during the handshake.

- NGINX will allow the handshake to complete, then enforce if the
  client was verified.
- APACHE (at least the last version I used) fails
  the handshake.